# How can I enumerate cancellations in Latex?

Tags: latex

I wish to number my cancellations as is done in textbooks.  For example,

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `\cancelto` from the `cancel` package:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[makeroom]{cancel}

\begin{document}
\begin{displaymath}
    \frac{2}{r^2} \cdot
    \cancelto{4}{\frac{\partial v_\theta}{\partial \theta}} +
    \cancelto{3}{\frac{\partial^2v_r}{\partial z^2}} \bigg\}
\end{displaymath}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect!  Thanks so much, this is just what I needed.